# Rails Override Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-negotiation

Is it possible to override Rails' render behavior for `:html` responses? I'd like to always render the same template (ignoring the magic view finding).

I'm writing a single page app, and this seems like it should be possible...basically if it's requested as `:json` it should render JSON, but if it's requested as `:html` it should pass the data on to the same view no matter what (where it will be rendered as JSON in the body).

Comment: Does this mean you want JSON within the `<body>` tags of the HTML. Or did you mean the body of the HTML response?

Comment: Sorry.. I think I don't understand your question. If you are writing a single page app, doesn't it mean that you will be making the requests via ajax? And if so, why would you want to render other html views? Wouldn't json be enough? If you want to reuse code on your json templates you can do so using jbuilder gem.

Comment: @AnthonyE I *do* want JSON rendered inside a `script` tag, yes. And @Aldana It's pretty common practice to bootstrap the needed data for a given page into a script element ahead of time; it saves on a request when you're starting your application.

Comment: @Crisfole Hey.. I've been thinking about this.. Did you find a work around? How about method_missing? Metaprogramming might be the answer here.

Comment: Hey, I just created my layout and a pile of empty `.html.erb` files. Works for me.

Comment: Haha, okay. I thought that's what you didn't want to do. Anyway, good 4 u!
In that case you don't even need to delete the yield part of the application.html.erb
I don't think the answer you picked as correct is the right answer (neither is mine), you should write your own. imho

Comment: The empty files don't bother me as much as the repeated content. I had forgotten I could use empty files for the partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the yield part on your application.html.erb, then you will alway get the application.html.erb without any partials.

Comment: Testing this, this might be what I need.

Comment: Nope. This results in a missing template exception.

Comment: Misunderstood. Got this working by adding the `application/index.html.erb` route that just renders the right script. I think this shoudl do the trick now...

Comment: I found your question interesting. Could you explain a little further how you got this to work please? :)

Comment: @Aldana right now it only works for the index view (still working out how to automatically render index in response to show, for instance). If you inherit from `ApplicationController` the inheritance tree is searched for files that match the action. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Crisfole I didn't know that, haha. It would be fun to look into ActionView methods and see if we can mess with that.

Comment: Lol, "Fun for some definition of Fun I'm not familiar with!"

Answer (score 0):

What if you define one single view and then after every action on every controller you render that view? Like this:

app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

app/views/home/home.html.erb

```
<!-- Whatever html code and script tags here -->
```

app/controllers/another_controller.rb

```
class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  def action
    render "home/home"
  end
end
```

You could even define an after_filter

### Edit

I tried this and it works. The after filter doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Hey @Aldana, thanks! A+ for effort. I was looking to *not* call `render` manually :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the JSON data as an instance variable?

**controller**

```
@json_data = whatever_model.to_json
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<script>
<%= @json_data %>
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Anthony, this is exactly what I was doing :) I was trying to figure out how to always render `application.html.erb` regardless of what controller or action was invoked.